# How do you do a two pass conversion in ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have tried the following:

```
$ffmpeg = "/path/to/ffmpeg";
$source = "/path/to/video/source.mp4";
$dest = "/path/to/video/dest.mp4";
$format = "%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s";
$a_rate = "44100";
$a_bitrate = "96k";
$v_bitrate = "3000k";
$resolution = "1280x720";
$outputfile = "/path/to/output.txt";
$pidfile = "/path/to/pid.txt";

exec(sprintf($format, $ffmpeg . " -i " . $source . " -vcodec libx264 -s " . $resolution . " -b " . $v_bitrate . " -pass 1 /dev/null && \ " . $ffmpeg . " -i " . $source . " -acodec libfaac -ar " . $a_rate . " -ab " . $a_bitrate . " -vcodec libx264 -s " . $resolution . " -b " . $v_bitrate . " -pass 2 " . $dest, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

Everything works perfectly if I do a single pass, but trying to do two passes like that doesn't work. What is the proper way to do it?

Update:

```
exec(sprintf($format, $ffmpeg . " -i " . $source . " -pass 1 -vcodec libx264 -s " . $resolution . " -b " . $v_bitrate . " -passlogfile " . $pass . " -f rawvideo -y /dev/null", $outputfile, $pidfile));
exec(sprintf($format, $ffmpeg . " -y -i " . $source . " -pass 2 -acodec libfaac -ar " . $a_rate . " -ab " . $a_bitrate . " -vcodec libx264 -s " . $resolution . " -b " . $v_bitrate . " -passlogfile " . $pass . " " . $dest, $outputfile, $pidfile));
```

Comment: Two pass encoding requires that you do a first pass which analyzes JUSt the video (e.g. audio is NOT considered). Those stats are recorded to a log file, which is then used in the second pass to produce the actual output video.: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html. Search for `-pass n`.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not very helpful. Refer to the ffmpeg output for actual error messages (and then add these messages to your question). Try to get the actual ffmpeg commands to work by using ffmpeg directly before you attempt to script it.

Comment: Take your PHP out of it, get the resulting command/parameters, and post on SuperUser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that putting the ffmpeg commands in the background with `$format = "%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s";` caused them both to be run at the same time and at that time there is no log file finished for the second pass to use. Backgrounding works fine with single pass because it has no dependencies, but I suppose a more involved solution is required to background two pass conversions. I am planning on using a queuing system.